# DB2 performance issue

Tags: db2, zos

I have to run a query against several million records comparing the SSN in one table against the derived SSN(I'm deriving it from a longer ID that stores the SSN as the first nine characters in this column) in another table.
In TABLE1, the SSN is stored as a decimal(9,0). In TABLE2, the SSN is stored as a char(23). I run a select that grabs the first 9 characters using this query that also checks to see the first 9 characters are numeric:

```
LENGTH(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(left(ee.award_id,9), '', '0123456789'))) = 0
```

DB2 ZOS9 won't let me cast a char to a decimal directly, meaning I have to cast my char to a varchar and then to a decimal(9,0) in order to compare against the SSN in TABLE1.

My question is:
Is it better to

1. double cast my char derived SSn into a varchar and then into a decimal and compare against decimal SSN in TABLE1 or

   ```
     cast (cast(left(ee.award_id,9) as varchar(9))as decimal(9,0))
   ```
2. is it better to cast my decimal SSN into a varchar  and my derived char SSN into a varchar and then compare the two or
3. are the two identical performance wise?

Thanks.

Comment: It'd probably be faster to cast the decimal column into character, then compare it to the (first 9 characters of the) char column (do SSNs have leading 0s?).  I'm surprised you _can't_ just cast it - the documentation lists it as castable.  Do you have the ability to change your table definitions?  Neither of your current columns are ideal - SSNs aren't really numeric (they're a string of digit characters, although should be stored unformatted), and storing multi-part keys is problematic.

Comment: I guess the best way to answer this question is to try both methods and compare the performance.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change table definitions. Trying them both out also isn't an option, after the first run the data will already be populated and the second run won't be necessary.

Comment: If TABLE1.SSN is in an index, and if that index might be used in this case, then using a function on the field and then comparing that might mean that such an index is no longer used. If an index is not a consideration, then I doubt the performance will vary much since the operation is likely to be I/O bound, not CPU bound.

Answer (score 1):

DB2 is exceedingly fast at running functions.  Don't spend your time optimizing that. You could potentially get your operations from stage 2 to stage 1 by choosing the correct predicate, but I don't think it's going to save you enough CPU/Time to be worthwhile.

You should be more concerned with whether you are disqualifying your query from using indexes by your choice of operations.  You haven't described whether there are any indexes involved, so we can't speak directly to that for you.  However:

*The main thing you can do to enhance the performance in this scenario is to attempt to get your SSN comparison to be indexed.*

Depending on what version you're running, you may be able to add an "index on expression" on the function to get your CHAR(23) derived SSN down to the 9 digits you want to compare to.   if you can do that, it may be worthwhile to add the index, run the query, and then drop the index.

You also haven't stated whether you have any performance/timing constraints.  *Without any constraints, I don't see any reason to try to optimize it at all.*